# runState and do blocks

Tags: haskell

This is a question more pertaining to do block usage than the state monad. In the following code we can use a do block directly with runState, but only by using flip to reverse the order of arguments so that the initial state to use is given first.

Why does one have to use the flip construct, in other words, how to put the do block as the first argument to runState?

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Control.Monad.State

type MapS = Map.Map Int String

-- Add an item (key value pair) to map
addItemToMap :: Int -> String -> State MapS ()
addItemToMap x s = modify $ Map.insert x s

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let r = flip runState Map.empty $ do
        addItemToMap 101 "one hundred and one"
        addItemToMap 1001 "one thousand and one"
  print r
```

Comment: `flip` *is* how you switch the argument order.

Comment: But my question is why cant you call runState with its arguments in the normal order in this context, not about what flip does. I don't know how to invoke the do in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to put the do block as the first argument to runState?

You can enclose the do-block in parentheses, as you would do with other expressions:

```
  let r = runState (do
        addItemToMap 101 "one hundred and one"
        addItemToMap 1001 "one thousand and one") Map.empty
```

That is a bit awkward, though, which is why `flip` is often used with `runState` in the manner you describe.

Answer (score 1):

The argument order for `runState` was probably chosen based on the assumption that the starting state (the second argument) would vary more frequently than the action (the first argument). If you want to flip the argument order, there's nothing else for it other than to use `flip` (or some other equivalent method). That's exactly what flip is for.

If you'd like, you can give `flip runState` a name to make it easier to reuse. For example, [lens has `&~`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/src/Control.Lens.Lens.html#%26~) for (the equivalent of) `flip execState`.